# array formatiing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an json array like this

```
 var data= [
  {
    "id": 24,
    "title": "BCOM",
    "start": "2014-08-05 12:59:00 PM",
    "end": "2014-08-05 2:59:00 PM",
    "description": "mcom",
    "DIFF": 120
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "title": "MCOM",
    "start": "2014-08-10 12:59:00 PM",
    "end": "2014-08-10 4:59:00 PM",
    "description": "mcom",
    "DIFF": 240
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "title": "MCOM",
    "start": "2014-08-11 12:59:00 PM",
    "end": "2014-08-11 8:59:00 PM",
    "description": "mcom",
    "DIFF": 480
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "title": "MCOM",
    "start": "2014-08-13 12:59:00 PM",
    "end": "2014-08-13 4:59:00 PM",
    "description": "mcom",
    "DIFF": 240
  }
]
```

I want to make this array having index with out double quotes and change some index names , and some other modifications by using javascript array functions.

like

```
var data = [
            {
                id: 24,
                title:"MCOM",
                y: 120


            },              

            {
                id: 26,
                title:"MCOM",
                y: 240,

            },
            {
                id: 29,
                title:"MCOM",
                y: 480,

              },

        ]
```

Please help me in this, Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?  It seems straightforward ! One simple way would be to convert that JSON to array , iterate through it and assign a new property `y` with the value of `DIFF` and `delete` other attributes ! You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` and code a callback function to do your modifications.

Comment: I think first data title should be `BCOM` isn't it?

Comment: actually the issue is i have to populate this data on to the high chart, so i have to format the array, like "id" to id, and "title" to title, and "diff" to y, how can we do this in javasript

Comment: That doesn't make a lot if sense to me. Properties names are always strings in JS. If you want to change how they appear in the *source code*, open a text editor and remove the quotation marks. Whether you used quotes or not doesn't make a difference at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes with quotes (`{ "title": "asdf" }`) are *equivalent* to indexes without quotes (`{ title: "asdf" }`) in javascript, except that you can use more symbols like spaces, brackets or keywords in the quoted version.

Also, in JSON, you *HAVE* to add quotes around indexes, otherwise it's not valid JSON.

About the modifications, you can use `Array.prototype.map()` to do this

```
var newData = data.map(function (el) {
    return {
        id: el.id,
        title: el.title,
        y: el.DIFF
    };
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array `map` function for this

```
var result = data.map(function (obj) {
    return {id:obj.id,title:obj.title,y:obj.DIFF};
})

console.log(result);
```

I'm assuming in the result there should be `BCOM` as `title` for `id`, 24. I this is a type that there it's written as `MCOM`.

what I think `""` shouldn't matter for keys.

Answer (score 0):

Do some googling ;-) it will help..

```
var data = '{ "name": "John Smith" }';       //Let's say you got this
data = data.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");  //This will remove all the quotes
data;                                         //'{ name: "John Smith" }'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: without the quotes it's not valid JSON.